# How to move a file to another existing directory in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile, qfileinfo

I am a beginner in Qt, one part of my project is moving a existing file to another existing directory? Can someone gives me a specific example? I am not sure whether I should use Qfile::rename(). I try write like this

```
QDir::rename("/home/joshua/test.txt","/home/joshua/test/test_c.txt");
```

but the error is  cannot call member function 'bool QDir::rename(const QString&, const QString&)' without object
         QDir::rename("/home/joshua/test.txt","/home/joshua/test/test_c.txt");
                                                                            ^

Sorry guys, all are my wrong, I asked a so unclear and so stupid question, I am so sorry for wasting your time, I am a beginner, before I asked this question, I really really had not noticed that this question have been asked before, because my level is to low. Because I am too naive, I can not ask question anymore, so please, please forgive me asked this question, I am too stress because I internship at a company, my project for me is quite hard so that I have no choice to do such a wasting your time thing, lastly, I want to say thank you for those who had seen my questions before.

Comment: You can use `QFile::copy()` function first to copy a file from one directory to another, and than delete the file you have copied `QFile::remove()`.

Comment: Before asking the question you should do a search, your question has already been answered before. To ask a good question you should read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#rename):

> **bool QFile::rename(const QString &newName)**
>
> Renames the file currently specified by fileName() to newName. Returns
>   true if successful; otherwise returns false.

In your case you must do the following:

```
QFile file("/home/joshua/test.txt");
file.rename("/home/joshua/test/test_c.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I was wondering Why QFile::copy function failed when i tried to copy a file from one drive to a different drive.

Comment: @Manjunath would be great to propose that question by providing a [mcve] directly asking why copy() does not work and if you rename(), I also think that should show an error message that tells us the reason.

Answer (score 0):

`QDir::rename()` is an instance method of `QDir`, so you need a `QDir` object on which to call it (and this directory will be the base for the filenames passed).  For your example, something like:

```
QDir d("/home/joshua");
bool renamed = d.rename("test.txt" , "test/test_c.txt");
```

You will want to make use of the return value.

Alternatively, you could use `QFile::rename()` - the default directory for that is the process's current working directory.